# Facebook login showing error in signed apk(Only if Facebook app installed, otherwise working fine )

Tags: android, facebook

The facebook login is working fine if there is no Facebook app installed in the device otherwise showing error. Please check screenshot of error.

**Key Hash Generater**

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\Mypc\.android\debug.keystore" | "C:\openssl\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary |"C:\openssl\bin\openssl" base64
```

Please let me know where i am  wrong.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

[image]

Comment: generate new keyHash and upload the this issue has been solve

Comment: But keyHash is always same...then why generate new..

Comment: when you generate keyhash then your key is final ya debug mode key.. if you keyhas is generate in debug key mode then when you publish app the  show this error..

Comment: Not sure but you asking... but i mentioned command above, that am using for key hash

Comment: I am saying when you use keyhash generater then you use alias and keystore is debug mode. you use sign alias and keystore  for your app.

Comment: Enter the above key hash in developer.facebook under your settings tab.

Comment: Like others already mentioned: Try re-exporting your key hash and adding it to your app settings. The key hash is not always the same; if you remove your key file, your android build setup will randomly generate a new one. You can also make sure that the export command doesn't feed error messages into the hashing algorithm, by trying the command without piping it into hashes first.